# How to evaluate $\cos{\frac{\pi}{8}}$?

Tags: trigonometry, radicals, pi, angle

I have to evaluate
$\cos{\frac{\pi}{8}}$
and I'm supposed to do so evaluating first 
$\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{8}}$
(since it's an exercise to practice half-angle formulas). Solving this second formula I get to

$\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{8}} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt[]{2}}$

where I'm stuck. I'm not sure it is an useful evaluation and, worst of all, I don't think that could help me solving 
$\cos{\frac{\pi}{8}}$.
I don't know how to get to 
$\frac{\sqrt[]{2 + \sqrt[]{2}}}{2}$, which is given as the proper answer. Could anyone explain it to me?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: So you used $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))$ to solve for $\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{8})$? Once you have $\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{8})$ you simply take square roots to obtain the result.

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi8.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track: note that
$$ \cos^2\Big(\frac{\pi}{8}\Big)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4} $$
and now take a square root to get $\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})$ (which is positive).

Comment: I don't really see how you get from $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ to $\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}$. Excuse me, but I think I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Comment: Wow, I feel so silly. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta -1$$

Put $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = 2\cos^2\frac{\pi}{8} - 1$$

$$\cos^2\frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2\sqrt{2}} = \frac{2 + \sqrt{2}}{4}$$

$$\implies \cos\frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos^2\frac\pi8=\frac12+\frac1{2\sqrt2}=\frac{2+\sqrt2}4$, $\cos\frac\pi8=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}2$.