# mupliplication of cosine of $\pi/2^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-functions

Let $x,y\in \{\frac{2\pi i}{2^m}\}_{0\leq i\leq 2^m-1 }$, where $m$ is a positive integer .

**Q** If we have that $\cos A=\cos x\cdot \cos y $, can we say that $A=\pi k$ for some $k\in \mathbb Q$.

For $m=1,2,3$, it is right. I do not know for the other cases.

Comment: This is false already for $m=4$. By [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem), if $A/\pi$ is rational the only rational values of $\cos A$ are $0$, $\pm1$, $\pm\frac12$. But [$\cos\frac{\pi}8\cdot\cos\frac{\pi}8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2334893/152568) is none of the above.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry, I do not follow. Since $\cos^2(\pi/8)\not\in\mathbb Q$, how to apply the theorem?